# Excel if function and conditions thereafter

Tags: excel, vlookup

Please see the table :
[image]

Based on the table, I need to display only those brand of cars manufactured by maruti in column E. I used =VLOOKUP("maruti",A:C, 2, FALSE) but gives result only in one cell.  When I drag it down, it brings in duplicate results.  Where am I going wrong in this? Is Vlookup the correct formula to achieve my requirement?

Comment: For your information, you are far better off for getting results by providing copy and pasted data into your question then your are providing a screen capture.

Answer (score 0):

OPTION 1)

IF formula

```
=IF(A1="Maruti",B1,"")
```

Place that in E1 and copy down.  When A in the same row has "Maruti" it will display the corresponding value from column B.  If it does not have Maruti, it will display "" which is essentially a blank for display purposes.

OPTION 2)

INDEX/AGGREGATE Formulas

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$15,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$15)/($A$2:$A$15=$D$2)-ROW($A$2)+1,ROW(A2)-1)),"")
```

Place that in E2 and copy down to E15.  Place the name your are looking for in D2.

For more information on formulas used follow the links:

- [AGGREGATE Formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df) Excel 2010 and later
- [IF Formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) Excel 2007 and later
- [IFERROR Formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) Excel 2007 and later
- [INDEX Formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) Excel 2010 and later
- [ROW Formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROW-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d) Excel 2007 and later

Comment: OMG !! quick reply just to make me realize that I have a lot to learn in an ocean called Excel where I am just learning to wet my toes. Thank You very much !

Comment: The If condition formula worked, the Index one failed.

Comment: @EthicalGamer I added cell reference lock to the first ROW(A2) so it is now ROW($A$2).  Let me know if that still does not work for you.

Comment: =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B109,'TEMPO DATA SCHR'!K:K,0)),0,IF(J109="Study Discontinuation",-1,0))  How to add an OR condition is the last statement where I can add 'End of Treatment" along with 'Study Discontiuation" ?

Answer (score 0):

I use array formula.

Select E2:E15 
then write `=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$15,SMALL(IF(IFERROR(MATCH($A$2:$A$15,$D$2,0),0),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS($A$2:$A$15)))),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROWS($A$2:$A$15))))),"")`

then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for late response, I was away from machine. The Index formula works now in Cell E2 where I get Wagon R but when I drag that down to cells below, the result is still same - Wagon R is repeating till E15

Comment: You do not have to drag the formula down, because the formula is written in cell E2 through E15.

Comment: Oh...I will search n do as I say